# Defining a function that maps a subset of matrices to the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having trouble defining a homomorphism $f$, that maps from $H$ (more on that below) to $\mathbb{Z}$. The question defined $H$ as a subset of $2 \times 2$ matrices of the form:
\begin{bmatrix}
1-a & -a\\
a & 1+a
\end{bmatrix}
where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Yeah, that's basically it; any help would be appreciated!

In short, I'm looking for a homomorphism $f: H \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is $H$ a group?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes it is, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a homomorphism unless you specify what algebraic operations it relates.  In this case $H$ turns out to be a group under matrix multiplication, and the map
$$ g: a \mapsto \pmatrix{1-a & -a\cr a & 1+a\cr} $$
turns out to be an isomorphism from the additive group $\mathbb Z$ onto $H$,
i.e. $g(a) g(b) = g(a+b)$.  Thus a homomorphism from $H$ to $\mathbb Z$ is the inverse 
$$ g^{-1}: \pmatrix{1-a & -a\cr a & 1+a\cr}  \mapsto a $$

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I forgot to specify the operation, but it is indeed matrix multiplication.